# Programmatically created button added resources doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control template in window's resource dictionary:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ActionButton1" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="Normal" Source="{DynamicResource EnableIconSource}"/>
        <Image Name="MouseOver" Source="{DynamicResource MouseOverIconSource}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Image Name="Pressed" Source="{DynamicResource PressedIconSource}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Image Name="Disabled" Source="{DynamicResource DisabledIconSource}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    ...
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When I use a button from xaml, resources in it work properly and images appear in their places

```
<Button Name="NewClient"                  
        Click="NewClientClick"                 
        Content="?????????? ??????????"                 
        Template="{DynamicResource ActionButton1}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <BitmapImage  x:Key="EnableIconSource" UriSource="/img/invite_next_normal.png"/>
        <BitmapImage  x:Key="MouseOverIconSource" UriSource="/img/invite_next_mouse_over.png"/>
        <BitmapImage  x:Key="PressedIconSource" UriSource="/img/invite_next_pressed.png"/>
        <BitmapImage  x:Key="DisabledIconSource" UriSource="/img/invite_next_disabled.png"/>
    </Button.Resources>           
</Button>
```

But when I try to do it in code images just appear transparent

```
var toolTip = new StackPanel();
var rslt = new Button {Name = "NewClient"};
rslt.Click += NewClientClick;
rslt.Content = "?????????? ??????????";
rslt.Template = FindResource("ActionButton1") as ControlTemplate;
toolTip.Children.Add(new TextBlock
{
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    Text = toolTipHeader
});
toolTip.Children.Add(new TextBlock
{
    Text = toolTipText
});
rslt.ToolTip = toolTip;

var resources = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"EnableIconSource", "/img/personal.png"},
                {"DisabledIconSource", "/img/personal_gray.png"},
                {"OverlayIconSource", "/img/not_come.png"},
            });
foreach (var resource in resources)
{
    var bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.BeginInit();
    bmp.UriSource = new Uri(resource.Value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    bmp.EndInit();
    rslt.Resources.Add(resource.Key, bmp);
}
return rslt;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the absolute paths for the images in the code portion. The initial path might differ and maybe the files don't get loaded.

Comment: The thing is that if i just use that way to put these images on button's content in stack panel - they appear properly too, even without absolute paths